# Frustrations with creating report types using multiple custom objects

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-report-type

I am trying to do something that at first seemed simple, but has turned into a frustration. Basically, I am trying to create a report that joins 3 custom objects, all of which are joined by master-detail relationships. The relationships work on the record level, meaning that I can add items that use the hierarchy of the custom objects just fine. But creating a report on more than 2 custom objects at a time still evades me.

Here is the object model I created (in a Developer Edition, but I haven't been able to do this in a Prod Sandbox either):

[image: Sample Data Model]

When I create a custom report type, the relationship selector includes both "Capybara Food" and "Capybara House" but I can only choose one or the other, not both. Is it possible to do this? I would like to create a custom report type that includes fields from all 3 objects, Capybara, Capybara Food and Capybara House, but everything I have tried so far has failed. I can create a joined report and use 2 different report types, but this seems messy and I've heard that joined reports are more trouble than they're worth (but I'm not sure if that's true).

Has anyone done anything like this? Thank you!

Comment: There are no other options without creating joined reports

Comment: You can go down a level in a report but if you do you can't go across. In other words parent and child not parent and children. Always been a thorn in reporting for me. I have not played with joined reports as you could not export them so they were useless and the Joins never seemed to show me what I needed but that may have changed in the last year or so.